# How to ignore specific charactor and new line using regex

Tags: regex, csv, apache-nifi

I am trying to validate a csv file using Apache-NiFi.

My CSV file has some defects.

```
id,name,address
1,sachith,{"Lane":"ABC.RTG.EED","No":"12"}
2,nalaka,{"Lane":"DEF",
"No":"23"}
3,muha,{"Lane":"GRF.FFF","No":"%$&%*^%"}
```

Here in second row,its been divided into two lines and third row has some special characters.

I want to ignore both the lines. For that I use `\{("\w+":"\w+",)*[^%&*@]*\}`, but this is not capturing row split error and new line.

I also used `\{("\w+":"\w+",)*[^%&*@]*\}$`, but it doesnt even get the right answer.

Comment: This maybe? `\{("\w+":"\w+","\w+":"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")\}`. Also It not crystal clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Eraklon, sorry, I updated question. My csv has some special scenarios to capture.

Comment: `\{("\w+":"[\w\.]+","\w+":"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")\}`

Comment: @Eraklon this doesn't. I just want to capture first line, other two should ignored. this doesnt capture that requirement.

Comment: Hmm for me it does. https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/7. Or you want to capture the whole line? With `1,sachith,` part too?

Comment: @Eraklon, yes. Whole line.

Comment: `^[0-9]+,[a-z]+,\{("\w+":"[\w\.]+","\w+":"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")\}$` Assuming it can start with a number which could have more than 1 digit and assuming the string after `,` is lowercase.

Comment: @Eraklon nope, it doesnt start with a number. But still this doesnt capture my requirement.

Comment: "1,sachith,{"Lane":"ABC.RTG.EED","No":"12"}" is the first line and start with a digit as you can see. So if you want an actually correct answer than specify what exactly what you want otherwise I (and others too) can not help you.

Comment: @Eraklon sorry, seems to be my error, could you please put it as an answer. so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you might looking for: `^[0-9]+,[a-z]+,\{("\w+":"[\w\.]+","\w+":"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")\}$`